# list(enumerate(x)) sometimes work and sometimes throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, enumerate

I understand enumerate() function in python however I found a strange behaviour of the same. For a list like

```
x = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

enumerate(x) creates an enumerate object and to retrieve the elements, we need to use list() function.
When I used

```
list(enumerate(x))
```

I got an error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.
```

And the **weird thing is (which is worrying me more)**, after trying for some time, I left it and moved on to something else.
Again, when I started running the SAME code (no change at all), it worked perfectly fine and I got the output as below (which is what we expect too)

```
[(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 'baz')]
```

The issues become weirder when I see that again next time (probably in my next session), the code produced the error and now you might have guessed my pain, it worked again in the next session.

**Has anyone faced such issues when a function works sometimes and throws an error other time?**
**What can be done in that case? Am I missing something?**

I am using Google Colab, I believe it doesn't matter.

**Edit:** As requested by @ZF007 in the comments, I am using the free version of Colab on a Windows machine & Python version is - 3.6.9

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/121L8fPNX31dyMUL4uEngkCi1uaF_js2j/view?usp=sharing) shows an error while the same code was working earlier.

Probably, something else is interfering with list(enumerate(x)) behind the scene, as pointed out by @Grismar and @Frank.

And as I mentioned earlier that the code is working now, so I am not trying anything else like changing the IDE.

Thanks

Comment: I hope it might be small syntax missing or may be Colab issue

Comment: Somewhere along the line you rebound "list" from the builtin `list` class to an instance of a list. `list = [1,2,3]` or something like that. Make sure that you don't use the names of builtin objects as variables.

Comment: You're sure the error was on this line?  Is it possible that the result of `list(enumerate(x))` might accidentally be being used as a function?  Are you assigning this list to a variable name that is accidentally overriding an internal function?

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ I am afraid, it's not. As I haven't changed anything in the code.

Comment: @tdelaney, I haven't used any name of any built-in object. You can see that in my code.

Comment: Then it might be the naming issue like you are naming as list

Comment: Is that your full code?

Comment: @FrankYellin I am not using list(enumerate(x)) as a function at all. I was just making a tutorial where I wanted to show how does enumerate work

Comment: @NanthakumarJJ, yes.

Comment: The actual issue is that you might be defined as some var list (as name)

Comment: you just try it in online editor or pycharm or any IDE it will give the res without error

Comment: "The actual issue is that you might be defined as some var list (as name)" I can not understand. Please eleborate.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/121L8fPNX31dyMUL4uEngkCi1uaF_js2j/view?usp=sharing
See, This was working earlier but when I started recording it (I clear output and run again) for the purpose of some tutorial, I didn't work

Comment: Post OS type/version, collab and python version.Then vote for reopening of question. `list(enumerate(x))` in Komodo IDE returns "null"/zero. When you use `x=list(enumerate(x))` and then `print(x)` expected output is printed. Thus either collab is having a bad day or there is multiple scripts running and it mixes "list" function somehow. This is not python performing a magic trick.

Comment: @ZF007,
OS Windows, Python version - 3.6.9
However, my question has nothing to do with OS or IDE. list(enumerate(x)) should give me the result [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar'), (2, 'baz')] which I was getting too. And I was running a single script. "collab is having a bad day" is not understandable.
I don't understand why my question got negative votes.
Anyways, Thanks all

Comment: Your question got negative votes because you didn't provide feedback on what you tried once people suggested possible causes - just like Python doesn't magically decide to do one thing the first time and something else the next, you can't expect people here to magically infer what your situation is. I still think the answer is as given though, as you've provided no further evidence and it's certainly the most likely.

Comment: If you update your question with requested information from the comment it might help down-voters change their opinion and thus remove it or even up-vote your question instead. I was asking you the version numbers because then its more likely to reproduce your unknown error. Colab version?

Answer (score 2):

Some people in the comments already pointed out that this error is likely due to redefining `list`, which 'shadows' the original definition.

For example:

```
x = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# this works, but redefines list
list = list(enumerate(x))

# this no longer works, since `list` is now the list created in the previous line
list = list(enumerate(x))
```

And you will see this error when the last line is executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<script filename>", line 7, in <module>
    list = list(enumerate(x))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

By the way: you note "enumerate(x) creates an enumerate object and to retrieve the elements, we need to use list() function". Perhaps you already know, but enumerate returns an iterable you can use in many ways, passing it to the `list()` function does return the contents in a list, but you could (for example) also use it directly in a `for` loop:

```
for i, obj in enumerate(x):
    print(f'{ob} is number {i}')
```

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned I haven't used any built-in names. I was just printing list(enumerate(x))

Comment: Since you're reporting behaviour that's intermittent, perhaps something else is redefining it without your knowledge. When you next have this problem, you would do well to `print(list)` and `print(type(list))`, so you can tell what `list` actually is at that time.

Comment: Watching the video.  It's clear that some thing is redefining 'list'.  There is no other explanation.  As @Grismar points out, the next time you see this, try printing out the value of `list` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, will check it.